# Xmldoc .selectsinglenode returns null

Tags: c#, xml

i'm really just trying to select the value listed at

```
    SOPDetail  
    TargetInfo   
DomesticJurisidiction
```

Each is a childnode of the other.  When I do an iteration i find the node DomesticJurisidiction however when I select using xpath I cannot find it.   Does anybody have a suggestion as to why?

```
        /*XmlNode targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SOPDetail/TargetInfo/DomesticJurisidiction");
        string haha = targetNode.InnerXml;*/

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.Name);
            foreach (XmlNode chldNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(chldNode.Name);
                foreach (XmlNode cNode in chldNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(cNode.Name + ":" + cNode.InnerXml);
                }
            }
        }
```

Like i mentioned the foreach iteration finds this node perfectly, why can I not select it using SelectsingleNode?

```
<SOPDetail LogId="324" LastModified="2007-05-20T09:20:50" xmlns="http://usop.ctadvantage.com/">
  <TargetInfo>
    <DomesticJurisdiction>Connecticut</DomesticJurisdiction>
    <ServedName>CT Demo Account (All State Corp)</ServedName>
    <ServedJurisdiction>New York</ServedJurisdiction>
    <NameDiscrepancyExists>false</NameDiscrepancyExists>
    <Defendant>Test</Defendant>
  </TargetInfo>
  <LawsuitInfo>
    <ReceiptDate>2007-05-20</ReceiptDate>
    <CreatedDate>2007-05-20T08:41:38</CreatedDate>
    <MethodOfService>Courier</MethodOfService>
    <LawsuitType>Other</LawsuitType>
    <LawsuitSubType>Documents requiring hard copy delivery</LawsuitSubType>
    <AnswerDate />
    <DocumentServed>Acknowledgment of Service</DocumentServed>
    <NatureOfAction>
      Notifying of Dft. 's No Opposition Summary Judgment Motion and Order
    </NatureOfAction>
  </LawsuitInfo>
  <CaseType>Standard</CaseType>
  <Remark />
  <CourtInfo>
    <Name />
    <AddressLine1 />
    <AddressLine2 />
    <AddressLine3 />
    <AddressLine4 />
    <City />
    <County />
    <State />
    <Zip />
    <Country />
    <Phone />
    <Fax />
    <Email />
  </CourtInfo>
  <AttorneyInfo>
    <Name />
    <AddressLine1 />
    <AddressLine2 />
    <AddressLine3 />
    <AddressLine4 />
    <City />
    <County />
    <State />
    <Zip />
    <Country />
    <Phone />
    <Fax />
    <Email />
    <LawFirmName />
  </AttorneyInfo>
  <AgencyInfo>
    <Name />
    <AddressLine1 />
    <AddressLine2 />
    <AddressLine3 />
    <AddressLine4 />
    <City />
    <County />
    <State />
    <Zip />
    <Country />
    <Phone />
    <Fax />
    <Email />
  </AgencyInfo>
  <CaseInfo>
    <CaseNumber />
    <Plaintiff />
  </CaseInfo>
  <DocId>123asdf234</DocId>
</SOPDetail>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to use Xml namespaces

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://usop.ctadvantage.com/");
XmlNode targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/x:SOPDetail/x:TargetInfo/x:DomesticJurisdiction", nsMgr);
```

Comment: Is that really necessary? I've never had to do that to make Xpath work

Comment: @Alan What do you think is the use of `xmlns="http://usop.ctadvantage.com/"` ? (Maybe your previous xml's didn't have a default namespace ?)

Comment: Still an XML document either way is it not? I do not need to even specify a xml namespace to use XPath. Are you claiming that if the XML document includes a namespace attribute that for XPath to work you need to add it and use it to do the XPath query?

Comment: @I4V You apparently need to have /x: in front of everythign to make it work

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware that XPath in C# forced you to add the default namespace. He still has to spell it right though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You spelled it wrong:

```
   /*XmlNode targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SOPDetail/TargetInfo/DomesticJurisidiction");
```

**DomesticJurisidiction**

vs.

**DomesticJurisdiction**

Comment: good catch it was a mistype of mine but it still doesnt find it

Comment: @Mike try // to specify the document root at the beginning of the XPath Query //SOPDetail/...